# How to make two JSF selectOneMenu that depend on each other?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

I have two instances of `selectOneMenu`, one dependent on the other. But my `processValueChange` in the bean is never invoked. JSP portion:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="slaPeriod" onchange="submit()" required="true"> 
  <f:selectItems value="#{LoginForm.periodList}"/>
  <f:valueChangeListener type="form.LoginForm" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I want to have the selected option and have an associated option in the next `selectOneMenu`. If say option is:

```
 OPTIONS       VALUES
 1. Weekly     1....52
 2. Monthly    Jan...Dec
 3. Quaterly   1...4
 4. Yearly     this drop down has to be disabled
```

Associated bean :

```
public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent arg0) throws AbortProcessingException 
{
  System.out.println("Inside Process Value Change!!");
}
```

This method is never invoked. Once this is done my problem will be resolved.

If you have any idea please help me, I'm really confused. Every time there is a refresh action on selection but this method of the bean is never invoked.

Comment: Welcome to SO!. You can use the formatting options when you post the code so it's more legible. 
Also, can you post the actual code of the page and the backing bean? Do you use JSF or JSP?

Comment: @pakore: I've fixed the question formatting. The code was all there, just not visible.

Comment: `throws AbortProcessingException` .. What framework are you using? Woodstock? What JSF impl/version and JSF component libraries are you using? You tagged JavaScript and Ajax as well, but actually the only JS in your question is `onchange="submit()"` and that's far from "ajaxical". More detail please.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Have you enclosed `<h:selectOneMenu>` within a `<h:form>` ?
- Does your bean implements `ValueChangeListener` interface?
- Is your bean inside the `form` package
- Is your bean session scoped or request scope? (I'd suggest to try with session scope)
- Is there any error on the console?